# If an application takes a really long time to start up, what is the best way to diagnose the problem?

Tags: gnome, pop-os, nemo

I have been using [Nemo](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/nemo) on [Pop_OS 21.04](https://pop.system76.com/) & GNOME 42 as I prefer it to the default GNOME file manager, Nautilus. It has been working great until recently where I have been observing delay in application startup. Clicking on a shortcut or launching from the terminal yields the same thing: the app starting after about 60 - 90 seconds. I do not see any spinner mouse pointer or other "busy" progress indicator, and one the app is open, closing it and re-starting exhibits the same behavior. I am also observing the issue in both my laptop and desktop machines, so this may be an issue with Nemo itself, and less likely a machine-specific configuration.

What is the best way to troubleshoot and diagnose the issue? I'm looking for any logs, performance metrics, or other error information gathering techniques that could help me determine why this is occurring.

Comment: `strace` could be a start.

Comment: In general, what @terdon suggests of course. However, in the particular case of Nemo, you could try A/ open a terminal and fire **nemo -q** then B/ fire **NEMO_DEBUG=Application NEMO_BENCHMARK_LOADING=1 nemo --debug** and observe detailed logs.